# Can the Facebook iPhone SDK access Facebook Social Plugin data?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4

Is it possible to use the Facebook SDK for iPhone to access Social Plugin comments etc like on this page

http://www.theodysseyonline.com/topstories/index.asp?article=690

Rather than having to use a UIWebView and embedding the Javascript? As this will be a problem as the users credentials will then not be persisted between articles

I just snooped the POST method when posting to a comment and this is the querystring data posted to: http://www.facebook.com/ajax/wallpost_ajax.php?__a=1

fb_dtsg=m45N0&app_id=156492904393524&xid=a182&c_url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fwidgets%252Fcomments.php&r_url=http%253A%252F%252Ftheodysseyonline.com%252Ftopstories%252Findex.asp%253Farticle%253D182&flavor=3&sig=cb3e733f844ae3f018c20a4c05605741&ret_now=1&reverse=&title=Expos%C3%A9%3A%20A%20Day%20in%20the%20Life%20of%20a%20Campus%20Area%20Bus%20(CABs)%20Driver.%20The%20Odyssey%20Online.&connected=1&external=1&loggedin=707387065&post_form_id=80c8e681fe9cf555fdaa33f4f8aeec00&name=Name&email=E-mail&wall_text=test&feed_story=1&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest